# Lightning Effect PyGame

Tags: pygame

I want to create a Lightning Effect Like http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=mmU2GAYGVSU for my game.

The following **[blog](http://drilian.com/2009/02/25/lightning-bolts/)** explains it briefly but I am not able to understand the following line:

```
midPoint += Perpendicular(Normalize(endPoint-startPoint))*RandomFloat(-offsetAmount,offsetAmount);
```

**UPD**: I went through older question posted at gamedev.stackexchange and found following explanation:

---

```
Normalize(endPoint-startPoint):
```

That line gets a unit vector (vector of length 1) from startPoint to endPoint

---

```
Perpendicular(Normalize(endPoint-startPoint))
```

then gets a vector perpendicular to that (i.e. at right angles to the line)

---

I want to know  whether python has inbuilt function for

- Getting a unit vector (vector of length 1) from startPoint to endPoint
- Getting a vector perpendicular to that (i.e. at right angles to the line)

Comment: The code on that page is not C#, it's [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode). It should easily translate to Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pygame has a vector math module. There you have the methods normalize and rotate, which you can use to construct unit and perpendicular vectors respectively.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html